# How to return values from a loop using Future.delayed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my function to take two dates and return a Double value for the progress bar of the remaining days to the final date.

My function gives only the first value (56.25% from the example)

Example:
Start: 15.07.2022
End: 31.07.2022
Now: 23.07.2022
Days left: 8 (16)
Progress: 56.25%
And on July 24, 2022 the function will return 62.5% and etc.

My experimental code: (Used seconds for clarity)

```
    // ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  progressDates(DateTime(2022, 7, 15), DateTime(2022, 7, 31));
}

double progressDates(
  DateTime date1,
  DateTime date2,
) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime nowDay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
  int dif1 = nowDay
      .difference(date1)
      .inDays; // The difference between the beginning and the current day
  int dif2 = date2
      .difference(nowDay)
      .inDays; // The difference between the curent and the end
  int allDays = date2.difference(date1).inDays;
  double inDouble = (dif1 / allDays) * 100;
  double temp = 100 / allDays;
  DateTime current = DateTime.now();

  Stream timer = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (i) {
    current = current.add(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    inDouble = inDouble + temp;
    return inDouble;
  }).take(dif2);

  timer.listen((percentage) => percentage);
  double result = timer as double;
  print(result);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not async and thus it will just finish once the percentage number is computed (without waiting for any `Future`). At that point all the async code in your function goes out of scope and will no longer be executed. You should probably remove everything to do with `Future` in your method and then probably use [Stream.periodic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.periodic.html) for that:

```
const stream = Stream<double>.periodic(Duration(days: 1), 
    (count) => progressDates(DateTime(2022, 7, 15), DateTime(2022, 7, 31)));

stream.listen((percentage) {
    print(percentage);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand how to do it right!

Comment: I tried that, but now I have some errors

Comment: I updated the code in the post to the new one from Stream.periodic

Comment: It is a very similar issue as it was before. Since your method is finished after executing once, the `Stream` will also be closed and no longer executes. You cannot cast that `Stream` to a `double` as well. My example is executing the whole method periodically.

Comment: Sorry Puelo, then how can you return a value from a function? I need one function to do all this and call it from main
The function should return a double value, but when I pass a value from the stream, it complains that it needs Stream dynamic

Comment: But if the function returns a double value it will only return a value once. Either you need to return a `Stream` from the function, or call the function repeatedly to get your percentage progress values. Or did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to do everything without using Future.delayed and Stream.periodic. I decided to just go with the current day